# Error when applying Seurat RenameCell function

Tags: r, seurat

For purposes of anonymization I need to rename the cell-names which include the study number in our dataset.

I have a Seurat-object with `test@assays$RNA$counts@Dimnames[2])` and `test@assays$SCT$counts@Dimnames[2])` having for instance: `"aab1.P2.299" "aab1.P2.311" "aab1.P2.315" "aab1.P2.318" "aab1.P2.319" "aab1.P2.321" "aab1.P2.322" "aab1.P2.338" "aab1.P2.349"`.

Here's what I did.

First, I got the list of original cell names in a new column:

```
test@meta.data$orig.cellname <- unlist(c(test@assays$RNA$counts@Dimnames[2]))
```

Next, I split this column:

```
test@meta.data <- test@meta.data %>% separate(orig.cellname, c('Cell_SNR', 'Cell_Plate', 'Cell_nr'))
```

Then I created a new cellname:

```
test@meta.data$new.cellname <- paste(test$SampleID, test$Cell_Plate, test$Cell_nr, sep = ".")
```

Where `SampleID` is a new anonymized sample ID.

Finally, I apply `RenameCell`.

```
test <- RenameCells(test, new.names = test@meta.data$new.cellname)
```

Here I assume the `dimnames` will be replaced throughout the `SeuratObject`, so at `test@assays$RNA$counts`, `test@assays$RNA$data`, `test@assays$SCT$counts`, and `test@assays$SCT$data`, but also at `test@graphs$SCT_nn`, and `test@graphs$SCT_snn`.

I get this error:

```
Error in new.cell.names.global[match(x = working.cells, table = old.names)] <- new.cell.names : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

I don't get this as far as I can see there aren't any 'NAs' in my new column.

I did search Google and found a few hints, which didn't help me further.

Solution 1:

https://github.com/broadinstitute/infercnv/issues/396

```
options(scipen = 10000)
test <- RenameCells(test, new.names = test@meta.data$new.cellname)
```

Still produces the same error.

I am not sure how to move forward from here. Any advice or suggestions would be great.

P.S. for obvious reasons I can't provide example data here.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. You seem to have a typo in `test@assays$RNA$counts@Dimnames[2]`; it should be `test@assays$RNA@counts@Dimnames[2]` (an `@` instead of `$` between RNA and counts). Did you check how `test@meta.data$new.cellname`looks before using it in `RenameCells()`?